# CSS Pagination doesn't work in the pagination library on codeigniter

Tags: css, codeigniter, paging

I've create a pagination with codeigniter library, but the css for current page is not shown the proper css.

PFB my code

```
public function news() {

 $this->load->library('pagination');


    $config['base_url'] = base_url('Home/news');
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('web_news')->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = 1;
    $config['num_links'] = 1;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $config['first_link'] =  'First';
    $config['last_link'] =  'Last';
    $config['next_link'] =  'Next';
    $config['prev_link'] =  'Previous';
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="text-center"><ul class="pagination"><li>';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</li></ul></div>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<div class="text-center"><ul class="pagination"><li class="active">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</li></ul></div>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data['news'] = $this->ModelNews->newsData();
    $data['newsCat'] = $this->ModelNews->newsCategory();
    $data['newsRecentPost'] = $this->ModelNews->NewsRecentPost();
    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $this->template->write_view('content', 'Web/news', $data, FALSE);
    $this->template->load();
}
```

This one the result of paging, the current page number is not on the rounded box, i've set the current tag open and close on the library

[image]

my html code

```
<section class="container blog">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Blog Column -->
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <h1 class="page-header sidebar-title">
                    KarAds Blog
                </h1>
                <!-- First Blog Post -->
                <?php foreach($news as $arrNews): ?>
                <div class="row blogu">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 ">
                        <div class="blog-thumb">
                            <a href="single-post.html">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/files/news/'.$arrNews['image'])?>" alt="photo" width="250" height="172">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                        <h2 class="blog-title">
                            <a href="single-post.html"><?php echo $arrNews['title']; ?></a>
                        </h2>
                        <p><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> <?php echo $arrNews['post_data']; ?> 
                            <span class="comments-padding"></span>
                        </p>
                        <?php echo $arrNews['description']; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
                 <?php endforeach; ?>


                        <?php echo $pagination; ?>
```

Comment: hi nothing much to seen in my html code

Comment: have you tried making a dummy pagination (raw html no PHP/CodeIgniter) with these classes? Do you get the desired result there?

Comment: @RahulM if i use without codeigniter it works properly, somehow it block the css for current page..